# How can i read from a file .dat with a lot of lines and gather just few values in arrays until EOF?

Tags: c++, arrays, eof

I have to make a program that read from a file .dat that have two columns but i'm interest just to one. Every columun contains a lot of values, stored each ones in  line. I want to gather them in groups (arrays) of 120 elements and then calculate the avarage value, proceeding like this until the EOF. Once calculated the avarage i save it in an external file.
The code that i wrote is like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int i, k=1;
double temp [120];
double tmean, total=0;

int main()
{

ifstream fin ("Data_Acquisition(1).dat");

if (!fin)
{
    cerr << "\nError: the file can't be open.\n" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

string line;

ofstream fout;
fout.open("tmean.dat", ios::out);
fout << "Tmean" << endl;

for(i=0; i<=120; i++)
{
    getline(fin,line);
    istringstream ss(line);    

    double col1;      
    double col2;      

    ss >> col1;  
    ss >> col2;

    temp[i] = col2;
    total += temp[i];
    k++;

}

tmean = total/k;

fout << tmean << endl;

}
```

My question is: once calculated the avarage of the first group of values, how can i say to the program to continue with others until the file ends?

Comment: Are you saying that you expect there to be multiple sets of 120 elements and you want to read those sets `while` not reaching `EOF`?

Comment: The array `temp` has 120 elements but your for loop iterates from 0 to i <= 120, which is 121 values.

Comment: Yes Derek, you got it! I have a file that every 120 elements change settings! thank you for the advertisment of the error in for loop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have an inner loop...

```
...
for(i=0; i<=120; i++)
{
    ...
}
tmean = total/k;
fout << tmean << endl;
```

...just wrap that in an outer for loop...

```
while (fin >> std::skipws && !fin.eof())
{
    for(i=0; i<=120; i++)
    {
        ...
    }
    tmean = total/k;
    fout << tmean << endl;
}
```

You might want to fix the bugs too: `k` starts at 1 and is incremented for each value read, so ends up being 1 more than it should me: start at 0; and Derek's already commented on another issue.

Comment: 120 is not a valid index for `temp`.

Comment: @Tony D Thank you very much for the answer. I don't understand the task of the conditiions 'fin >> std::skipws' in the while loop. Sorry, i am a beginner in c++ as you see...

Comment: @PaoloOrsatti The `fin >> std::skipws` advances to their the end of the file or the next character that's not whitespace, the latter implying there should be another set of 120 values.  By then differentiating these two conditions and exiting the loop if we're at end-of-file, you ensure that you only enter the loop and attempt parsing if there's actual data to parse.

Comment: @Derek I've made the correptions that you segnalized me, i compilate and execute the program but it doesn't work. Like if it is an infinit loop. I'll make another question with the code modified.